# Select results based on nearest date window

Tags: sql-server, datetime, window-functions, recursive-query, gaps-and-islands

I have a SQL Server table as follows. I would like to group by name and place of test taken, order by date ascending as partition based on above mentioned grouping.

now a configurable window of eg:4 days is provided. In below table if first test taken date is
02/01/2019 (1st Feb) - its score is taken, and any other test score which has been retaken within the next 4 day window shall not be considered. If record also falls within 4 day window of already excluded item example row id - 4 , that also shall be excluded.

Any SQL statements for this logic is much appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE test(  
    [recordid] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [name] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [testcentre] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [testdate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [testscore] [int],
    [Preferred_Output] [int],
    [Result] [nvarchar](75) NULL
)

GO
INSERT INTO test
           (
    [name],
    [testcentre],
    [testdate],
    [testscore],
    [Preferred_Output],
    [Result]  )
    VALUES
('George','bangalore',' 02/01/2019',1,1,'Selected as first item -grouped by name and location'),
('George','bangalore',' 02/02/2019',0,0,'ignore as within 4 days'),
('George','bangalore',' 02/04/2019',1,0,'ignore as within 4 days'),
('George','bangalore',' 02/06/2019',3,0,'ignore as within 4 days from already ignored item -04-02-2019'),
('George','bangalore',' 02/15/2019',2,2,'Selected as second item -grouped by name and location'),
('George','bangalore',' 02/18/2019',5,0,'ignore as within 4 days of previous'),
('George','Pune',' 02/15/2019',4,3,'Selected as third item'),
('George','Pune',' 02/18/2019',6,0,'ignore as within 4 days of previous'),
('George','Pune',' 02/19/2019',7,0,'ignore as within 4 days of previous'),
('George','Pune',' 02/20/2019',8,0,'ignore as within 4 days of previous')

GO
select * from test
GO



+----------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+------------------+
| recordid |  name  | testcentre |  testdate  | testscore | Preferred_Output |
+----------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+------------------+
|        1 | George | bangalore  | 02/01/2019 |         1 |                1 |
|        2 | George | bangalore  | 02/02/2019 |         0 |                0 |
|        3 | George | bangalore  | 02/04/2019 |         1 |                0 |
|        4 | George | bangalore  | 02/06/2019 |         3 |                0 |
|        5 | George | bangalore  | 02/15/2019 |         2 |                2 |
|        6 | George | bangalore  | 02/18/2019 |         5 |                0 |
|        7 | George | Pune       | 02/15/2019 |         4 |                3 |
|        8 | George | Pune       | 02/18/2019 |         6 |                0 |
|        9 | George | Pune       | 02/19/2019 |         7 |                0 |
|       10 | George | Pune       | 02/20/2019 |         8 |                0 |
+----------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that a recursive query is required for this. You want to compare the dates across *consecutive records*, so this is a kind of gaps-and-island problem, where want to identify the start of each island.

Window functions can do that:

```
select t.*,
    case when lag_testdate is null or testdate > dateadd(day, 4, lag_testdate)
        then testscore
        else 0
    end new_core
from (
    select t.*, lag(testdate) over(partition by name, testcentre order by testdate) lag_testdate
    from test t
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2c8e55e71c23126abe47f75d0b6104eb)**

Comment: Hello GMB, would like to add a retest condition along with lag am working with RANK function, is that the correct approach?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=447a5d2c33b04346e70dab0a8d098655